# Android - NullPointerException when trying to implement Adapter from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, implementation, android-adapter, baseadapter

I am loading a `Fragment` and in turn the `Fragment` creates an `Adapter`. The `Adapter` has an `interface`. The Fragment that loads `implements` the `Adapter`.
There are no errors when I initiate `mCallback`.

Here is code in Adapter:

```
Scanlist mScanlist; 
ScanlistListener mCallback;

public Scanadapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Scanmodel> d, Resources resLocal){
    mActivity = a;
    mData = d;
    res = resLocal;
    sInflater = (LayoutInflater)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mScanlist = (Scanlist) mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.scanlist);
    try {
        mCallback = (ScanlistListener) mScanlist;
        Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(mCallback)+ " here");
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(mScanlist.toString()
                + " must implement ScanlistListener");
    }
}

private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    private int mPosition;
    OnItemClickListener(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCallback.scanlistclick(v, mPosition);
    }
}

public interface ScanlistListener{
    public void scanlistclick(View v, int i);
}
```

When I click on an item in the list im getting a `NullPointerException` yet the `try statement` does not give an `error exception` initiating the `mCallback` variable.

```
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at net.xxxxx.adapter.Scanadapter$OnItemClickListener.onClick(Scanadapter.java:140)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4489)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18803)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
08-22 10:19:09.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your findFragmentByID  does not find the layout element it was looking for, it will return null. You then assign null to mCallback. Assigning null with a cast will not trigger an exception. Perhaps step through your code with the debugger, and ensure that your view is being found and mCallback is not set to null.

Comment: yep, mCallback is set to null, how do I set mCallback?

Comment: Has your fragment layout been inflated _before_  you call findFragmentByID?

Comment: i updated the method in my question so show you where I initiate Inflater

Comment: I sent the adapter `this` from the fragment, your answer put me on the right path